# Positioning a circle img overlapping div

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I'm learning React at the moment so I'm putting together a simple search site. Where you can search for TV-shows using the TVMaze API.

I am trying to put one img overlapping the div below to give this effect:
[image: Picture showing the desired look]
At the moment I only have this:
[image: Picture showing the current look]

Now My question is how do I make the picture overlap as I want? I "know" that I should use z-index to get one over the other but I'm not sure how to then move the img over the underlying div.

This is my return in my render() in my react component:

```
    return (
  <div>
    {show.image !== null && (
      <div className="result-container">
        <img className="result-poster" src={show.image.medium} alt="" />

        <div className="result-card">
          <h2 className="result-title">{show.name}</h2>
          <div className="result-ratings">
            <i className="material-icons">star_border</i>
            <h3 className="result-rating">
              {show.rating.average === null && "N/A"}
              {show.rating.average !== null && show.rating.average}
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

And the corresponding scss:

```
.result-container {
width: 300px;
margin: 2rem;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-around;
text-align: center;
.result-poster {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}
.result-card {
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    .result-ratings {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-content: center;
    }
    i,
    h3,
    h2 {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
}
```

It also looks like the picture in the img is being distorted in some way that I don't know how to "undo" either.

Much appreciate the help as I am quite new to this kind of development.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the css, if you need more help just tell me.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.result-container {
width: 300px;
margin: 2rem;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
.result-poster {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}
.result-card {
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 80px;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    .result-ratings {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-content: center;
    }
    i,
    h3,
    h2 {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
  }
}
```